# Encoding error on Android Studio (R.java file) after rebuild

Tags: java, android, android-studio, r.java-file

Recently i have imported an android studio project from some repo. The project initially was being coded in linux/ubuntu enviroment with no problems. Now i want to work in windows, but build is giving me some errors in R.java (auto generated file):

```
error: illegal character: '\u00a9'
```

Some information i have found on internet suggest me this solution:

> set the right file encoding in your build.gradle script:

```
compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251' // write your encoding here
```

I have added, but still the same issue. What i am doing wrong?

---

Resources:

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    ...
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'
...
```

R.java  (lines with error):

```
...
    public static final int country_réunion_code=0x7f0a0381;
    public static final int country_réunion_name=0x7f0a01df;
    public static final int country_réunion_number=0x7f0a0382;
...
```

Settings for encoding:
[This is the image for settings if needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sew6O.jpg)

Android Studio 3.1.3

Comment: Why would you have a variable with an special character `é` and not uppercased? Just refactor and change the variable name...

Comment: This is **not** a variable generated by me... this is **automatic** android studio generated file... R.java file. @RafaelPalomino